# No output on console

Tags: c, console

I am just starting to learn C, this is probably a very easy question for you guys but your help is very appreciated. I am trying to use this code to count the number of characters inputted into the console but when I hit enter it just gives me a blank new line, like `printf` hasn't worked. Where am I going wrong?

```
int c, number;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
++number;
}
printf("%d\n", number);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you hit enter, the program increments the counter because it gets a newline character and waits for more input. You have to feed the program an EOF with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Linux, Unix, Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Windows).

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter is not EOF as already pointed by other answers.
2. After inputting EOF you will get wrong result as you have not initialized `number`. You are incrementing garbage value. Initialize it to zero.

   `int c, number = 0;`
3. In this way newlines will also be counted. If you want to skip them then you need to test that `c` is not equal to `'\n'` before incrementing `number`.

Comment: +1 for the intializing number, I wondered why I was getting a very strange character count :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're under windows, press `Ctrl`+`Z`and then enter. If under linux, press `Ctrl`+`D`. That will cause end of file.

Answer (score 0):

`enter` is not EOF on a console it is either ctrl-Z (windows) or ctrl-D (unix)